# Excel - Getting #VALUE! for only one instance. All others work well

Tags: arrays, excel

Background:
A client of mine rents a building to different companies, and takes readings of both the Electricity meters and Water meters, so as to bill the companies according to their usage.

Invoices are then created, specifying the start and end month of the invoice, so as to retrieve the readings from the appropriate columns of the selected months.

I have the following formula in Excel:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Invoice_Sheet_Readings, SMALL(IF(Invoice_Sheet_Readings=$D$63, ROW(Invoice_Sheet_Readings)-25),ROWS($G$68:G68)), MATCH($D$63,$F35:$CC35,0)+1), "")}
```

Where:

- `Invoice_Sheet_Readings` is a range of cells from where the data is checked and retrieved (Grey area in the images)

  - `$D$63` is the Month & Year (selected from a dropdown list - eg. December 2017) - Darker green area in the images

What this does is - it compares the Month and Year (eg. December 2017) to its equivalent in the range (grey cells), and populates the table (green areas) to be used in invoice calculations. The green areas are where I have this formula.

The problem:
Everything works well, except for ONE instance.

So, when Electricity meters are selected, ALL data retrieval works well for every tenant.

When Water meters are selected, data retrieval works well for all tenants EXCEPT ONE.

When I evaluate the formula for those tenants where all works well, it gets the row number, then matches and retrieves data from the appropriate column.

In the instance of the tenant where the problem lies, while evaluating it shows as though it's going to match the row numbers, then give a `#VALUE!` error.

I'm totally baffled. Can't figure it out at all.

Updated: There is one specific line (highlighted in image 9) that is the culprit. If I assign it to another tenant the new tenant's Water reading calculations show the same error, while the original tenant's calculations now work well.

[Image 1: Data of Electricity meters (grey areas) - no problems here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y5tj.jpg)

[Image 2: Data of Water meters where data retrieval from the formula works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKd8r.jpg)

The repeated months in the columns are for comparing to the month that is selected from a dropdown list (darker green areas in following images)

[Image 4: Above formula working well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnY1U.jpg)

[Image 5: Formula evaluation where formula is working well. The '1' shown between the green dots refers to the row the data has been found in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL0sa.jpg)

[Image 6: The only instance where the formula is not working, and thus no data has been retrieved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kowVg.jpg)

[Image 7: The error shown in the formula evaluation. This is only for the Water readings of ONE tenant. The same tenant's electricity readings work fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOqDh.jpg)

[Image 8: Formula evaluation showing the beginning of the formula and the end of the formula one step before giving the VALUE error. The other cases evaluate in the same way without errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM1ts.jpg)

[Image 9: (Updated) The line that is the culprit - but I still don't know why.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZMzN.jpg)

Comment: Are there any #VALUE! errors in the source data?

Comment: None. The grey areas are populated without errors from the readings sheets itself, even for the tenant with the problem. I also double checked that the dates are inputted properly. They are.

Comment: Remove the IFERROR - does it actually return #VALUE! (the evaluate formula dialog is rubbish) or #NUM!, or something else?

Comment: When I removed the IFERROR it returned #VALUE!

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of the Evaluate Formula window precisely one step prior to that in which the #VALUE! error first appears?

Comment: I just updated the question to include the picture at the very bottom.

Comment: And you did array enter the formula?

Comment: Do you have any circular references within the workbook?

Comment: @Rory yes, the formula is entered as an array with curly brackets - shown above. XOR LX there are no circular references. In all other instances, including Electricity readings for the same tenant, there is no problem with the same formula.

Comment: I just manage to figure out that there is one specific line (highlighted in image 9) that is the culprit. If I assign it to another tenant the new tenant's Water reading calculations show the same error, while the original tenant's calculations now work well.

Comment: I know the original formula was array-entered; I wanted to check that you array-entered it after removing the IFERROR part?

Comment: I have to apologise - I found the mistake, which is totally mine. One of the readings was not entered as a number, but included a date too. So Excel tried doing the calculations but failed. Sorry for your time and effort.